# Update expiration date of a OAuth Token in a JHipster App

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, token, jhipster, access-token

I work on a JHipster generated application with Angular4/Spring.

When I log on the app, I can call the API for 1800 seconds.
However when I run a request, the expiration date of my token should be reset and I should not be disconnected after this time.

In my table `oauth_client_details`, I have the fields `access_token_validity` and `refresh_token_validity` on 1800 each.

Is there something else to set up so that the token is properly updated?

Comment: Thats not how Oauth works.   Your access token will work for a given amount of time then you will need to use the refresh token to request a new access token.

Comment: Oh okay I see, but I'm surprised that this process is not set up in jhipster. I can see the refresh token in the database but it seems unused

Comment: What version of JHipster are you using? Monolith or Microservices? This should all be handled by Spring Security OAuth (since we refactored everything in September 2017).

Comment: I Used 4.7 (From September 2017!) to generate a Monolith app. The front-end didn't use the refresh token to extend the duration of the session. I post the code that I used to work around the problem, maybe it's no longer relevant in the latest versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a trick to refresh session duration with the refresh token.

In **auth-oauth2.service.ts**, replace *authSuccess()* function and add a *refresh()* one.

```
authSuccess(resp) {
    const response = resp.json();
    const expiredAt = new Date();
    expiredAt.setSeconds(expiredAt.getSeconds() + response.expires_in);
    response.expires_at = expiredAt.getTime();
    this.$localStorage.store('authenticationToken', response);
    if (this.refreshSubcription !== null) {
        // cancel previous refresh
        this.refreshSubcription.unsubscribe();
    }

    // refresh token 5 seconds before expiration
    this.refreshSubcription = Observable
            .timer((response.expires_in - 5) * 1000 )
            .take(1)
            .subscribe(() => this.refresh());

    return response;
}

refresh() {
    const data = 'refresh_token=' + this.getToken().refresh_token + '&grant_type=refresh_token&scope=read%20write&' +
        'client_secret=<SECRET-TOKEN>&client_id=<CLIENT-ID>';
    const headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.getToken().access_token
    });

    this.http
        .post('oauth/token', data, {headers})
        .map(this.authSuccess.bind(this))
        .subscribe();
}
```

Remember to modify the *logout()* and login() methods accordingly.

```
login(credentials): Observable<any> {
    const data = 'username=' + encodeURIComponent(credentials.username) + '&password=' +
        encodeURIComponent(credentials.password) + '&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&' +
        '<SECRET-TOKEN>&client_id=<CLIENT-ID>';
    const headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + this.base64.encode('<CLIENT-ID>' + ':' + '<SECRET-TOKEN>')
    });

    return this.http
                .post('oauth/token', data, {headers})
                .map(this.authSuccess.bind(this));
}

logout(): Observable<any> {
    if (this.refreshSubcription !== null) {
        // cancel previous refresh
        this.refreshSubcription.unsubscribe();
    }
    return new Observable((observer) => {
        this.http.post('api/logout', {});
        this.$localStorage.clear('authenticationToken');
        observer.complete();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked with JHipster generator **4.6.0**, If that works for someone I made these changes in **application.yml**, and works for me.

```
jhipster:
    security:
        authentication:
            oauth:
                # Token is valid 1 day
                token-validity-in-seconds: 86400
```